# How do I continue looping, even through an error? Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, while-loop, loopback

I have two conditions in my story using the question that I made to ask the users.

The first condition is true and second condition is false. In the first condition, if it's true, I want the program to finish. In the second condition, if it's false, I want to loop back to the question that I asked.

I have the following code, but so far it will loop back if the first is true and the second is false.
Any ideas?

```py
invalid = ValueError

def age():
  user_input = input("Enter your Age")
  try:
    val = int(user_input)
    print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
  except ValueError:
    print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")

while invalid:
  age()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make things easier and just use a boolean as your continuation flag, rather than the ValueError:

```
ask_again = True
def age():
  user_input = input("Enter your Age")
  try:
    val = int(user_input)
    print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
    ask_again = False
  except ValueError:
    print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")

while ask_again:
  age()
```

Does that look like what you want? Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to execute a while loop is to just use while True and then break from the loop once the condition is satisfied

```py
def age():
  while True:
    try:
      val = int(input("Enter your Age"))
      print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
      break
    except ValueError:
      print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")

age()
```